# Setspace package not working

Tags: packages, errors, setspace

I've tried searching, and I couldn't find my answer, so I hope I'm not re-asking stupid stuff. That being said, I'm a total noob to LaTeX. As such, this question is probably ridiculous and stupid.

I'm trying to double space my paper. I added the setspace package into my header, no problem. However, when I build the file, the bottom line in the Output window (there's probably a more technical term for it) says:

`LaTeX-Result: 0 Error(s), 0 Warning(s), 0 Bad Box(es), 0 Page(s)`

Instead of the 6 pages I have now. This seems like something deceptively easy, help is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example where this occurs?

Comment: Anytime I add setspace to the /usepackage{} command in the header. It builds ok (aside from showing that I have 0 pages) and produces the PDF, but nothing inside the document has changed.

Comment: Please add a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: This is a TeXnicCenter problem. I have seen it before on my own PC. I think it has nothing to do with the miktex issues Axel mentioned in his answer as I was using a full install when I experienced the same problem.

If I remember correctly, errors and warnings are still shown and only the page count is not displayed. You could probably just ignore this, your PDF will be correct.

Answer (score 3):

Are you using MikTeX as TeX system and TeXnicCenter as editor? Please note that this combination has serious issues when using not-yet-installed packages.

See: http://www.miktex.org/2.9/issues

So either follow the workaround given on the link above, or use a proper (La)TeX editor, like TeXworks (which is part of the MikTeX distribution), TeXmaker(X) etc.

Especially if you are a "noob to LaTeX" I would recommend not to use TeXnicCenter at all, but something like TeXworks instead which simply works out-of-the-box. Just start TeXworks, enter your text, select "pdfLaTeX" in the toolbar and press the green start button.

Comment: While it sure is matter of taste, I disagree that TeXnicCenter isn't good for noobs; I'm relatively new and have always used TC. It's true that there are a few issues that you have to research and work around (but after all, this is what you do with LaTeX all the time). Besides that, I like it way better than TeXworks. As for the issue with installing packages on-the-fly: I think it seems pretty silly to want to be asked for confirmation whether you want to install a package -- after all it was _you_ who wrote `\usepackage{thisnthat}` in the preamble, which implies that you do want to use it.

Comment: @doncherry TeXnicCenter hasn't got support for UTF-8, at least in the production version. That's a big obstacle nowadays.

Comment: @egreg: I'd say that really depends on what you're using it for. For my papers in German and English, latin1 has always sufficed so far. If you're going for Arabic, Japanese or Cyrillic characters, Unicode seems to be a must.

Comment: @doncherry The announcement of 2.0 Alpha 3 was in May 2010 and nothing changed from then. It seems that development has stopped.

Comment: I still think that TeXworks is better for beginners. Just write down what steps do you need to get TeXnicCenter working. You need to install it, you need to install a PDF viewer, you need to setup TC so that it actually works with that PDF viewer, you need to setup TC so the PDF viewer will automatically close when you do a (La)TeX run, you need to get SyncTeX working with TC etc. All of this is working with TeXworks out-of-the-box, you don't even need to install it because it will already get installed with MikTeX.

Answer (score 1):

Related to Martin H's comment, I've seen this as well with TeXnicCenter.  I think the final `LaTeX-Result: 0 Error(s), 0 Warning(s), 0 Bad Box(es), 0 Page(s)` is generated by TeXnicCenter parsing the output log; however, for whatever reason the parser seems to break if the root filename is really long.  If you scroll up a bit in the output log you'll see a line that reads:

```
Output written on <filename>.pdf (<X> pages, <Y> bytes).
```

With the proper number of pages.

My suggestion is to try shortening the filename so that the above output line doesn't wrap in the output log.  That has worked for me in the past.